# Github action for displaying the number of out of date package dependencies

Tags: github-actions

How can I add a shield to my .README that displays the current number of out of date dependencies in my package.json? Whenever I run my github action "Firebase CI", I'd like the the badge to update the with current the number of out of date dependencies at build time. The badge looks like this:

[image]

I currently have an action configured for building and deploying my create react app to firebase hosting. It looks like this:

```yml
name: Firebase CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    env:
      CI: false
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/f

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      # - run: npm ci
      - run: npm install -g yarn
      - name: yarn install, build and test
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn build
      - name: Archive Build
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: build
          path: ./build

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Download Build
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          FIREBASE_PROJECT: myapp
```

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "start": "FAST_REFRESH=false react-scripts start",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.tsx ."
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
}
```

So how could I have such a badge for my react project's .README?